# CursorLoader cancelled when activity is paused

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I have a `CursorLoader` that provides data to a `ListFragment`. I have the notification mechanism correctly configured in my `ContentProvider` with:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

and

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)
```

When I select a list item, a new child `Activity` is opened and in the `onCreate()` of this `Activity` I do a query modifying the item details.

I know the notification is fired and the `CursorLoader` re-queries the content provider.

The problem I'm facing is that **sometimes** my `CursorLoader` is cancelled because the parent `Activity` is being paused (or stopped) and the `onLoadFinished()` never gets called.

When the `CursorLoader` is cancelled, even if I re-init the loader `onResume()` of the `ListFragment`, I can't see any change in the data:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(URL_LOADER, null, this);
}
```

I'm using support library v4.

I'm assuming `CursorLoader` updates the parent `Activity` even when it is on background. Do I need to restart the loader when the `ListFragment` resumes?

**(edit)**

I forgot to mention that I'm creating and starting the loader from a `ListFragment`.

After some debugging, I found that when the `ListFragment` is stopped, the loader manager cancels all current loaders for the fragment.

In my case, when the new child activity is created, a db change triggers a notification that makes the loader perform a re-query. If the query does not finish before the parent fragment stops, the loader is canceled and the old cursor is still valid. When I navigate back to this parent activity with the `ListFragment` from the child activity, the data shown is from the old cursor. In this case, the notification is lost and I have to restart the loader `onResume()`.

I did a test where I modified the db only after 10s since the child activity started, and because the loader was not canceled (because the parent activity was already stopped), I received a new cursor when returning to the parent activity.

Can anybody help me find a solution that does not involve a forced re-query (`restartCursor()`) every time the parent activity resumes?

Comment: when do you call .notifyChange?

Comment: @pskink in the ContentProvider when I change an item of my ListFragment. This happens in the child activity, in onCreate().

Comment: ok what flags are you using in a CursorAdapter? I'm using the same mechanism and notifications are not lost

Comment: Only CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER.

Comment: see java docs about that flag, the last sentence

Comment: @pskink, I tried with no flags but I got the same behaviour.

Comment: " In my case, when the new child activity is created, a db change triggers a
notification that makes the loader perform a re-query" i dont get it: why a notification if you want to query a content provider in order to show the details?

Comment: @bruno Did you found a solution to your problem. I think I have a similar problem. And same as you I am forced to use restartLoader() in onResume(). Notifications just do not work.

Answer (score 0):

When using the support library, you need to use `getSupportLoaderManager()` instead of `getLoaderManager()`, But you can only get it from the FragmentActivity. So try using this code instead:

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(id, null, this);
```

Comment: I tried this approach but the behaviour is the same. The loader is canceled when the child activity is started.

Comment: There is only one LoaderManager per Activity, and LoaderManager ties loaders to the lifecycle of their creating components, so, if what you are trying to do is share the loaders between activities, it can't be done.